# Ulam number の効率の良い求め方について

Tags: ruby, アルゴリズム

Ulam number とは以下の性質を持つ数である。
（http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ulam_number）
①今まで現れた相異なる２つの Ulam number の和で表そうとしたとき、1通りしか出来ない。
　 注）相異なる２つの Ulam number の和で表せないときは、Ulam number ではない。

N = 339 とし、
N 以下の Ulam number を次のように求めてみた。

```
N = 339
ary = [1, 2]
(3..N).each{|i|
  cnt = 0
  (0..ary.size - 2).each{|j|
    break if ary[j] + ary[j + 1] > i
    (j + 1..ary.size - 1).each{|k|
      l = ary[j] + ary[k]
      break if l > i
      cnt += 1 if l == i 
    }
  }
  ary.push(i) if cnt == 1
}
p ary
```

しかし、このコードは
相異なる２つの Ulam number の和が i となるものを数えるのに、
逐一調べている。
（例えば、i = 100 のときでも、1 + 2 から調べている。）

どのように Ulam number を探せば効率が良いか教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manyamaさんの回答のコードで感じたことを。

計算済みの数列を`ary[0]`、`ary[1]`…、`ary[n - 1]`とすると

```
ary[n] >= ary[n -1] + 1 = ary[0] + ary[n - 1]
```

が成り立ちます。

なので`j`が0の場合、回答で`ary.include(i - ary[j])`としている部分は最後の要素だけを判定すればよいです。

さらに`j - 1`の時の探索結果が

```
ary[k] <= i - ary[j - 1] < ary[k + 1]
```

であれば、次の`j`の時は

```
i - ary[j] < i - ary[j - 1]
```

を満たすので`k`から降順に判定すると効率的です。

この二点で計算オーダーがO(n)ぐらい減らせるかと思います。

Comment: N　= 10 ** 4 でも十分以前の方法より速く求まるのが実感できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

相異なる２つの Ulam number の和が i となるものを数えるということは、
片方が ary[j] と決めたとき、もう片方は i - ary[j] でなくてはいけない。
よって、以下のコードとなる。

```
N = 339
ary = [1, 2]
(3..N).each{|i|
  cnt = 0
  (0..ary.size - 2).each{|j|
    break if ary[j] + ary[j + 1] > i
    cnt += 1 if ary.include?(i - ary[j])
  }
  ary.push(i) if cnt == 1
}
p ary
```

出力結果
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 11, 13, 16, 18, 26, 28, 36, 38, 47, 48, 53, 57, 62, 69, 72, 7
7, 82, 87, 97, 99, 102, 106, 114, 126, 131, 138, 145, 148, 155, 175, 177, 180, 1
82, 189, 197, 206, 209, 219, 221, 236, 238, 241, 243, 253, 258, 260, 273, 282, 3
09, 316, 319, 324, 339]

(追記)
pgrho さんの回答を見て次のように改良しました。

```
N = 339
ary = [1, 2]
(3..N).each{|i|
  cnt = 0
  k = ary.size - 1
  (0..k - 1).each{|j|
    break if j >= k
    m = i - ary[j]
    while ary[k] > m
      k -= 1
    end
    cnt += 1 if ary[k] == m && j < k
  }
  ary.push(i) if cnt == 1
}
p ary
```

コードに無駄な部分があれば、ご指摘いただければ幸いです。